# Where to find a list of echolink nodes in a specific country

Tags: echolink

I google search "[Echolink Nodes in Germany](http://www.google.com/search?q=echolink%20nodes%20in%20germany&oq=echolink%20nodes%20in%20germany&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l2.4140j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)" and no results show of nodes which are in Germany. I search repeater book, but it seems like it only has North American nodes.

Is there a good source where I can find all of the Nodes in a specific country?

I use echomac which doesn't have the option to choose a country

Answer (score 2):

If you download and install the Echolink software, under Stations you can simply choose Locations/Europe/Germany and it will list all currently active nodes.

Comment: I have a mac and use echomac

Comment: Here is the echolink list of online users, at least it's in a browser where you can search the info: http://www.echolink.org/logins.jsp

Comment: http://www.smeter.net/stations/call-prefixes-by-country.php allows you to find the call sign prefixes for Germany, so for Germany, eleminate everything not between DAA-DRZ or Y2A-Y9Z .